# Python: Why does unittest assertEqual throw an error instead of failure on these lists?

Tags: python, python-unittest

Python 2.7 and 3.4: Why does the `test_unexpected_error` test throw an error instead of a failure?

```
import unittest


class TestLists(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_unexpected_error(self):
        self.assertEqual([0] * 1000 + [1], [1] + [0] * 1000)

    def test_fails_as_expected(self):
        self.assertEqual([0] * 1000 + [1], [0] * 1000 + [0])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The error is:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Traceback (abridged - a recursion error is a recursion error is a recursion error is....)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sotest.py", line 7, in test_unexpected_error
    self.assertEquals([0] * 1000 + [1], [1] + [0] * 1000)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 513, in assertEqual
    assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 743, in assertListEqual
    self.assertSequenceEqual(list1, list2, msg, seq_type=list)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 722, in assertSequenceEqual
    pprint.pformat(seq2).splitlines()))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/difflib.py", line 920, in compare
    for line in g:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/difflib.py", line 1038, in _fancy_replace
    for line in self._fancy_helper(a, best_i+1, ahi, b, best_j+1, bhi):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/difflib.py", line 1051, in _fancy_helper
    for line in g:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/difflib.py", line 1038, in _fancy_replace
    for line in self._fancy_helper(a, best_i+1, ahi, b, best_j+1, bhi):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/difflib.py", line 1051, in _fancy_helper
    for line in g:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/difflib.py", line 1038, in _fancy_replace
    for line in self._fancy_helper(a, best_i+1, ahi, b, best_j+1, bhi):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/difflib.py", line 1051, in _fancy_helper
    for line in g:

(...)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/difflib.py", line 965, in _fancy_replace
    cruncher = SequenceMatcher(self.charjunk)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/difflib.py", line 219, in __init__
    self.set_seqs(a, b)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/difflib.py", line 231, in set_seqs
    self.set_seq2(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/difflib.py", line 285, in set_seq2
    self.__chain_b()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/difflib.py", line 318, in __chain_b
    for i, elt in enumerate(b):
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: Is there a stack trace?

Comment: Looks like you found a real bug.

Comment: bruno beat me to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks to be a known [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue21253).

If you don't want the unit test to display the difference between the lists when it fails you can do this alternate test:

```
self.assertTrue([0] * 1000 + [1] == [1] + [0] * 1000)
```